# Should the user's password field be included (with all the hassle) on the settings page?

Tags: forms, password, settings, accounts, profile

What is the best implementation of changing user settings with respect to the password change?

I have a rails app, and if a user goes to the "update profile" page, the password field has to be re-entered every time even if the user is going there simply to change their address or job title or whatever.

Might 2 pages be better? One for updating the users profile, and another for the users password. It seems like overkill to have a completely separate page for changing the password.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the level of security you require. Perhaps you can conditionally require the password depending on which fields the user has altered?

Answer (score 1):

### Neither approach

If possible, settings should be on **one page**, and you should **not have to re-enter your password**.

There are several ways to do this.  Here are two:

[image: settings]

In the second approach, the password form is hidden and is displayed when the user wants to change the password.